# Trying to use tfestimate and invfreqz to find coefficients of second order linear system

Tags: matlab, estimation, transfer-function

I would like to use [`tfestimate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) and [`invfreqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/invfreqz.html) to determine coefficients in a second order linear system.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
Nsamp = 2^16;  
t = linspace(0,100,Nsamp);  
x = square(t/30) + .1*randn(1,Nsamp);  

Num = 1;  
Den = [20 2 10];  
sys = tf(Num, Den);  

y = lsim(sys,x,t);  

[txy, phi] = tfestimate(x,y);  
[b, a] = invfreqz(txy,phi,2,0);
```

In this way, I am hoping that the values in `b` are good estimates for the original values used in `Den`.
However, my values are completely off. If I plot the bode of the system and the `tfestimate`, I see that they are not close at all. I have tried fiddling with all the settings in `tfestimate` -- window type & size, sampling frequency, nfft, etc but I can't seem to get an accurate answer.
I'm not sure I understand enough about `tfestimate` spectral analysis to tune it properly. Or perhaps there is a better to doing it altogether that I don't realize.

Also, I do not have access to the System ID toolbox so I can't use anything from that.